# Eliminar elemento de una matriz Java

Tags: java, matriz

Tengo una duda para un ejercicio en el cual es esta simulando una sala de cine en java, tengo las clases y métodos, pero uno que me está dando problemas es el de eliminar una posición. Tengo un método para comprar un asiento a partir de una matriz predefinida, pero no sé cómo construir el código para eliminar dicha posición.

```
  `private static void comprarBoleto() {
        boolean flag;
        int comprarFila;
        int comprarColumna;
        do {
            System.out.println("\n      Ingresa un Número de Fila = : ");
            comprarFila = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\n      Ingresa un Número de Columna || : ");
            comprarColumna = scanner.nextInt();
            flag = SalaPrueba.verificarAsiento(comprarFila, comprarColumna);
        } while (!flag);

        SalaPrueba.comprarBoleto(comprarFila, comprarColumna);    
    }`



Public void comprarBoleto(int comprarFila, int comprarColumna) {
        this.precio = calcularPrecio(comprarFila);
        ticket += 1;
        ingresoActual += precio;
        sala[comprarFila][comprarColumna] = 'X';
        System.out.println("\n      !Compra Exitosa! "+ 
                "Precio de la Boleta: $ " + precio +
                "\n !Por Favor Presentarse con 15 Minutos de Anticipacion!");
```

Comment: En rigor no se puede eliminar un elemento de una matriz. Pero puedes tener un valor para asiendo comprado y otro para no comprado. Es decir una matriz con bools: boolean array[][]= new boolean[10][20]; cuando vendes asiento lo pones en true y hay una devolución de un asiento lo colocas en false

Comment: Gracias, logre entenderlo de esa forma y quedo solucionado.